# What is the difference between Kaal Bhairav ​and Mahakal?

Tags: shaivism

Can someone tell me the difference between Mahakal (Mahakala not Mahakali) and Kaal Bhairav (KalBherav)? Thanks
Sorry for my transcription errors, I am Westerner, I don't know Hindi and I don't have much knowledge on the iconography of deities.

Comment: Mahakal is the consort of Mahakali so it's Lord Shiva's another name .. Kal Bhairva however is an incarnation of Lord Shiva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hinduism, both Mahakal (Mahakala) and Kaal Bhairav (Kālabhairava) are forms of Lord Shiva associated with the concept of time and destruction. However, they are distinct manifestations with different attributes and symbolism.

1. Mahakal (Mahakala):

Mahakal, also known as Mahakaleshwar, is a revered form of Lord Shiva worshiped mainly in Ujjain, Madhya Pradesh, India. He is considered the presiding deity of the famous Mahakaleshwar Jyotirlinga temple in Ujjain.

Kalika Purana, Chapter 18, Verse 35

**महाकालः स्मशानवासी नीलकण्ठः शिवो शिवः।
भगवान् जटिलो भीमः सर्वलोकपितामहः॥**

Meaning: Mahakal is the resident of cremation grounds, with a blue throat, auspicious, and the grand father of all worlds. He is Bhagavan (the supreme deity), adorned with matted hair, and formidable.

Mahakal is associated with time and death, symbolizing the transient nature of life. He is often depicted as dark complexioned, wearing a garland of skulls, and holding various weapons. Devotees seek his blessings for protection and liberation from the cycle of birth and death.

2. Kaal Bhairav (Kālabhairava):

Kaal Bhairav, also known as Kālabhairava, is another fierce form of Lord Shiva and is widely revered across India. He is considered the protector of the city of Kashi (Varanasi) and is often associated with the concept of time, destruction, and annihilation.

Rudra Yamala Tantra, Chapter 16, Verse 29

**कालो भैरव उच्यते भूतपतिर्हितैषिणः।
सर्वज्ञो देवकल्पोऽसौ सुखकारी च नित्यशः॥**

Meaning: The Lord is called Kālabhairava, the ruler of beings, and the destroyer of the wicked. He is all-knowing, divine, and the giver of eternal happiness.

Kaal Bhairav is depicted with a terrifying appearance, adorned with a garland of skulls, and carrying a trident and a skull-cup. He is believed to grant protection to his devotees and liberate them from fear and negative influences. Worshiping Kaal Bhairav is believed to alleviate the effects of malefic planetary influences and grant spiritual growth.

In summary, both Mahakal (Mahakala) and Kaal Bhairav (Kālabhairava) are forms of Lord Shiva, each representing different aspects of time, destruction, and protection. Their worship is deeply rooted in Hindu traditions, and devotees seek their blessings for different purposes and spiritual goals. The verses and scriptural references provided highlight some of their attributes and significance.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nitesh, your answer is very complete with nice text references